Facebook - Create new account button not able to click
Unable to click on Create New Account button in Facebook home page
In execution it displays Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"a[id='u_0_0_Qk']"}
Tried same using xpath getting same error Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[5]//a[@id='u_0_0_Qk']"}
Url: https://www.facebook.com/


instead of putting the screenshot of the html, copy and paste the html you are working with in the question.

Create new account

The selector for the element is not right.
The element you are trying to interact with has a dynamic ID, which will change on every page load.
If you load the page again and check the ID, it is not u_0_0_Qk or u_0_0_aG, as in your comment.
So, you can see that the id has changed from your screenshot and the comment.
Instead of selecting the element by id, check the data-testid attribute.
The value of it remains constant.
So you can use the CSS selector :
a[data-testid='open-registration-form-button']

or XPath:
//a[@data-testid='open-registration-form-button']

